# (shell script linux) Traverse recursively by user's input

Tags: linux, shell, recursion

I am using ksh on linux system. I want to ask user whether they want to traverse this directory. If yes, then list files and perform similar check for sub directory.

Comment: Any code you can show us? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use "find", with the "-ok" option for this:

```
find . -type d -ok echo {} \;
```

This will search, in the current directory (i.e. ".") and below, for all things of type "d" (i.e. directories) and ask you if you want to echo the name of the directory. The "\;" just terminates the command.

Of course, you want to do something different from "echo", such as your actual processing, but you should get the idea.

Here is an example. You can see the directory name is echoed when I say "yes" to the "ImageMagick" and "nytprof" directories, but nothing happens in other directories:

```
find . -type d -ok echo {} \;
"echo ."? n 
"echo ./dir"? n
"echo ./ImageMagick"? y
./ImageMagick
"echo ./nytprof"? y
./nytprof
```